# I am a Python beginner self teaching trying to query a SQL database with an entry widget binding the enter key to return the search of a table

Tags: python, sql, search

I am trying to create a search app that only shows the data not modify
any explanation why it is not working will be helpful

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import pyodbc

cgb = tk.Tk()  # "cgb" is my root definition

cgb.title("CGB Price Check ver-1.0")
cgb.geometry("800x650")
cgb.iconbitmap("E:/python/images/cbc_icon.ico")

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=CGB-1\PCAMERICA;'
                      'Database=creserver;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


cursor = conn.cursor()

var = Entry(cgb, width=40, text=" ", font=("ariel", 12), borderwidth=2, fg="black", bg="#7DD0F2")
var.focus_set()
var.get()
var.pack()
var1 = var.get()

def search(event):
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT ItemName, Price FROM inventory WHERE Store_ID = 1001 AND ItemNum=(?)", (var1,))
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    while row:
        lb1 = tk.Label(cgb, text=("Item Name:", row[0][0]))
        lb1.pack()
        print("Item Name:", row[0][0])
        print("Price:$", row[0][1])
        row = cursor.fetchall()


var.bind("<Return>", search)

search(var1)

cgb.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is your code give error output? If so, please provide the error

Comment: no error just when i enter the search parameter nothing happen because when i press enter on the keyboard it is not executing